# Interface IPyomoTask has already been defined

Tags: python, pyomo

I am using Pyomo, and I would like to a series of optimizations where some results of the previous optimization is used for next.

AgOpt.py

```
import pyomo
import pyomo.opt
from pyomo.environ import *
import numpy as np

AvailLand = 330
AvailWat = 945

AlfWat = 4
AlmWat = 1.5
CornWat = 2.5

AlfMaxY = 7
AlmMaxY = 6.5
CornMaxY = 7

AlfPrice = 132
AlmPrice = 610
CornPrice = 300

AlfCostAcre = 681
AlmCostAcre = 3478
CornCostAcre = 610

N=[1,2,3]

model = ConcreteModel()
model.x = Var(N, within=NonNegativeReals)
model.Obj = Objective(expr=model.x[1]*(AlfMaxY*AlfPrice-AlfCostAcre)+\
                      model.x[2]*(AlmMaxY*AlmPrice-AlmCostAcre)+\
                      model.x[3]*(CornMaxY*CornPrice-CornCostAcre), sense=maximize)
model.con1=Constraint(expr=model.x[1]<=100.1)
model.con2=Constraint(expr=model.x[2]<=30.03)
model.con3=Constraint(expr=model.x[3]<=200.2)
model.con4=Constraint(expr=model.x[1]+model.x[2]+model.x[3]<=330)

model.dual=Suffix(direction=Suffix.IMPORT_EXPORT)


opt = SolverFactory("glpk")
results = opt.solve(model)
model.solutions.load_from(results)

results.write()
model.Obj.display()
model.x.display()
model.dual.display()
```

The problem is that when I solve the code (using Spyder) once, the second time it raises this error:

"Interface IPyomoTask has already been defined"

And I have to exit Spyder and enter again.

Any suggestion?

Python and anaconda versions:

Python 3.5.2 |Anaconda 4.2.0 (64-bit)| (default, Jul  5 2016, 11:41:13) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-2-f27cc52b2eaf>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('//fresno/users/escriva/Documents/Python Scripts/AgOpt.py', wdir='//fresno/users/escriva/Documents/Python Scripts')

  File "C:\Users\escriva\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\envs\py35\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 866, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\escriva\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\envs\py35\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "//fresno/users/escriva/Documents/Python Scripts/AgOpt.py", line 9, in <module>
    import pyomo.opt

  File "c:\users\escriva\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda2\envs\py35\lib\site-packages\pyomo-4.2.10784-py3.5.egg\pyomo\opt\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pyomo.util.plugin import PluginGlobals

  File "c:\users\escriva\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda2\envs\py35\lib\site-packages\pyomo-4.2.10784-py3.5.egg\pyomo\util\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pyomo.util._task import pyomo_api, PyomoAPIData, PyomoAPIFactory

  File "c:\users\escriva\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda2\envs\py35\lib\site-packages\pyomo-4.2.10784-py3.5.egg\pyomo\util\_task.py", line 102, in <module>
    class IPyomoTask(plugin.Interface):

  File "C:\Users\escriva\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\envs\py35\lib\site-packages\PyUtilib-5.2.3601-py3.5.egg\pyutilib\component\core\core.py", line 600, in __new__
    raise PluginError("Interface %s has already been defined" % name)

PluginError: Interface IPyomoTask has already been defined
```

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace for the error you are getting?  Also, can you post the driver you are running in spyder?  The error is coming from the Plugin system, but I cannot duplicate it using simple models/drivers.

Comment: I have edited the question, thanks for your reply. Let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: So far I have not been able to reproduce this behavior with a simple example (I am running Python 3.5.2 with spyder -- but not within anaconda, and have tried Pyomo 4.2.10784, 4.4.1, and trunk).  Can you share your `AgOpt.py` script?  That may provide some hints.

Comment: I have included the code in the question. Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: I cannot reproduce the behavior you are seeing on either CPython 3.5.2 nor with Anaconda 4.2.0.  That said, there are couple things that catch my eye: 1) You have an old version of Pyomo installed (4.2).  First try uninstalling `pyomo` and `pyutilib`, then install the current release with `conda install -c conda-forge pyomo` 2) You don't need either the `import pyomo` nor the `import pyomo.opt` lines in `AgOpt.py`.  3) you have a strange installation where you have python 3.5 installed into an `anaconda2` directory.  Did you switch Anaconda versions at some point?

Comment: SOLVED... I was using an environment to run python 3.5 (because I was originally using python 2.7). So I uninstalled everything and I installed anaconda again using only python 3.5 and now it works.

Thanks for your help jsiirola!!!!

Answer (score 2):

SOLVED... I was using an environment to run python 3.5 (because I was originally using python 2.7). So I uninstalled everything and I installed anaconda again using only python 3.5 and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe as an extra insight into this problem, it appears as if your Spyder installation tries to access another source of PyUtillib.

This happened to me after installing the user version of Pyomo (with `conda install -c conda-forge pyomo and pyutillib`) and then moving to a developer version (cloning the git repositories).

To solve it, it sufficed to remove the packages managed by Anaconda through `conda-forge` (`conda remove -c conda-forge pyomo and pyutillib`) and then following the installation instructions here: https://github.com/Pyomo/pyomo/issues/90#issuecomment-335051682